# How to fetch webhook Params

Tags: php, json, webhooks

From my website, I'm trying to save data in another server, the whole webhook preview :

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token token=sfg999666t673t7t82" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H 'Authorization: Bearer oibk2s757l0et81s47uhq47a89w7qbnv' -d '{   
   "entity":"order",
    "order_id":{{ item.entity_id }},
    "customer_id":{{ item.customer_id }},
    "increment_id":{{ item.increment_id }},
    "title": "New order placed",
    "message": "Your order has been placed , With Order Id {{ item.increment_id }} will let you know once processed",
    "type": 2
}' -X POST 'http://299.247.3.52/fcm/webhook/receive/index/'
```

But Following code is not working:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
Or 
print_r($_REQUEST)
```

How to get header/post values?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
> ```

You need to stop doing too many different steps in one go.

You mashed two things together here, which each can fail individually - you could not *have* any actual POST input data to read, *or* trying to decode what was read as JSON might fail. The way you have written this, you can only look at what `$json` contains afterwards, so you won’t be able to tell *which one* of those two steps actually failed.

```
$request_body = file_get_contents("php://input");
$json = json_decode($request_body, true);
```

Now if this fails, you can check the result of each step separately. You could f.e. do a `var_dump($request_body);` first now, to see if you actually received the POSTed data this way.

In this case, you will likely discover that that was the case - but trying to decode it as JSON afterwards failed.

And if you really send the cURL request as you have shown it above, then that is no real surprise - because that data is not valid JSON to begin with.

> ```
> "order_id":{{ item.entity_id }},
> ```

These parts in the double curly braces here surely are meant as *placeholders*. You need to substitute them for actual values first, before you send this. This needs to become something like `"order_id":1234,` in that place, only then will it be valid JSON.

Answer (score -1):

do the requesting within your PHP code too. not on separate script.